# VertexAI Model Prediction an Explanation returning empty error message

Tags: google-cloud-aiplatform

Asking for a prediction with explaination from the VertexAI SDK, REST, and CLI return HTTP code 400 with no error message

From the REST API:
https://-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/:explain
the returned message is:
{"error": "b'{"error": ""}'"}

The Python SDK for endpoint.explain(instances=instances, parameters=parameters) method returns this error:
InvalidArgument: 400 {"error": "b'{"error": ""}'"}

gcloud ai endpoints explain  --region= --json-request=/request.json
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai.endpoints.explain) HTTPError 400: {"error": "b'{"error": ""}'"}

To ensure that I hadn't made a mistake, I tried the predict method. The SDK method aiplatform.Endpoint.predict(instances=instances, parameters=parameters) returns a valid response

It appears that the REST method is correct [based upon documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.locations.endpoints).

It also appears that only a correct instances argument is needed for the explain method [based upon documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.Endpoint), but I did try it without parameters, and with including a deployed_model_id and timeout.

I think the CLI is correct, though I am not as versed with using it as REST or the SDK [based upon the documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/ai/endpoints/explain)

I would have expected these methods to work, or at the very least provide an information about why the request was incorrect.